how to mix (or time average) two density matrix?
Given two density matrix $\rho_1,\rho_2$ with the same size, how to get a mix state of the two matrix,
$$
\rho = \frac12 (\rho_1+\rho_2)?
$$
e.g. there are two quantum channel both of them have 4 qubits, with density matrix $\rho_1,\rho_2$.
Now, we combine two channels, and there are 8 qubits in channel.
My objection get density matrix $\frac12 (\rho_1+\rho_2)$ from $\rho_1,\rho_2$.
With given state $\rho_1,\rho_2$, is it theoretically permissible to construct state $\frac12 (\rho_1+\rho_2)$ after some operation?
Any operation is permissible.
Naïvely, I can tomography both $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$, and add them in classic computer. Then prepare it in quantum circuit. However, I think this method is so stupid.
Can we get $\frac12 (\rho_1+\rho_2)$ in quantum channel without classic computer or at least no using tomography?

The mixed state $$\rho = \frac{\rho_1 + \rho_2}{2},,$$ is a valid quantum state. However, can you try to make it a bit clearer what exactly you are trying to do with quantum channels? The following part is unclear: "if there are two the same quantum channel both of them have 4 qubits, the state of the two channels evolve independently into. If we conbine two channels, now there are 8 qubits in channel, is it theoretically permissible to get density matrix on four qubit in system?"

I made the statement clearer. Looking forward to your answer!

i don't understand what you're asking. What does "there are two quantum channel both of them have 4 qubits, with density matrix ρ1,ρ2" mean? How does "combining two channels" give "8 qubits in channel"? I don't understand what the sentence starting with "my objection get density matrix" is trying to say at all. To "get" a mix of two states, you can just flip a coin and generate one of the two conditional to the outcome

I feel sorry for ambiguity.  Your answer inspired me. Thx very much.

Your question is a bit confusing because it is not clear what you mean by "combine two channels into an 8 qubit channel", but maybe the following suffices?:

Prepare $\rho_1$ on qubits $q_0$ to $q_3$.
Prepare $\rho_2$ on qubits $q_4$ to $q_7$.
Prepare $|+\rangle$ on qubit $q_8$.
Apply $\text{CSWAP}$ gates between $q_i$ and $q_{i+4}$ conditioned on $q_8$.
Discard (trace out) $q_8$.
You effectively have $\rho = \frac{1}{2}(\rho_1 + \rho_2)$ in both $q_0$ thru $q_3$, and $q_4$ thru $q_7$.


Appreciate your answer very much. I apologize for the ambiguity. Your answer accomplished my objective perfectly.
